# Three.js white texture is rendered as gray

Tags: three.js, textures

What could cause to render white texture as gray? I need it to be white, but can't find the reason why it appears as gray.

I tried both Basic and Lambert materials (transparency is on), I have AmbientLight and DirectionalLight both created with (0xffffff, 1) and direction is set. I use OrthographicCamera, there is no fog set up. Tried to move plane closer and farther from the camera. The used image is 8-bit transparent PNG, white part of the surface is 100% opacity.

On the right part of this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

you can see that sky color is pure white but rounded square texture is rendered as gray. Three.js rev 77.

[image: White square.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I had copied renderer parameters from some example without knowing what all of those do. Problem was caused by following line:

```
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
```

Comment: Looks like the default for `MeshBasicMaterial` is to do toneMapping as well, so adding `toneMapped: false` to the options will fix it up!